# Removing special characters using Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have data stored in Cassandra 1.2 as shown below. There is special character under sValue - highlighted as bold. How can I use hive function to remove this ?

Date | Timestam | payload_Timestamp        | actDate | actHour | actMinute | sDesc | sName             | sValue
---------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------
        2014-06-25 00:00:00-0400 |             2014-06-25 08:31:23-0400 | 2014-06-25 08:31:23-0400 |           06-25-2014 |                    8 |                     31 |                  lable | /t1/t2/100/200/11/99 |   **2743326591.03\x00**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regexp_replace() function.

More details available on 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF