# Charset, Accents, Special Characters in Apache Hive

Tags: hadoop, character-encoding, hive, diacritics

**The Problem**

I’m having quite some problems with my Hive tables that contain special characters (in French) in some of their row values. Basically, everything that is a special character (like an accent on a letter or other diacritics) gets transformed in pure gibberish (various weird symbols) when querying the data (via Hive CLI or other methods). The problem is not with column names, but with the actual row values and content.

For exemple, instead of printing "Variat°" or any other special character or accent mark, I get this as a result (when using a select statement):

```
Variatï¿½ cancel
```

**Infos & Conf**

- The Hive table is external, from a CSV file in HDFS that is encoded in charset iso-8859-1. Changing the original file encoding charset doesn’t produce any better result.
- I'm using a Hortonworks distribution 2.2 on RedHat Enterprise 6. The original CSV displays correctly in Linux.

**The Question**

I've looked on the web for similar problems but it would seem that no one encountered it. Or at least everybody uses only English when using Hive :) Some Jiras have addressed issues with special characters in the Hive table column names - but my problem is with actual content of rows.

- How can I deal with this problem in Hive?
- Is it not possible to display special characters in Hive?
- Is there any "charset" option for Hive?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I’m currently stuck.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Other similar threads propose to escape such special characters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513231/removing-special-characters-using-hive

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue but since my source file was small used notepad++ to covert it to UTF-8 encoding.